# Joomla Form w/ File Upload for iOS & Android?

Tags: joomla, joomla3.4, chronoforms

I've used chronoforms for my Joomla forms and it's great, but I haven't been able to figure out how to make the file upload process clean and efficient for iOS and Android devices with it.

What Joomla 3.x form is good at handling file uploads for iOS and Android? Or, how do I setup chronoforms to do it?

As is, in Android you are given the choice of several unfamiliar apps to choose a file, not Gallery or any form of file browser.  If there was a way to tell the OS the type of file it needs to be trying to upload it would work great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronoforms will work and can easily be setup to cleanly handle uploads from mobile devices.

For the desired file field select Edit and scroll down to the Extra Params box.

In there, add the following link of code:
accept=images/*

This presents users with a choice of apps to select a file, both file browsers and photo gallery.  It also allows uploads from all file types and is the cleanest way I have discovered to handle uploads of documents and other types of files.

Additionally, if you wish you can force users to take a photo with their camera that will then be attached by adding this line in addition to the above line:
capture=camera